# Запуск gif-картинки по клику мыши

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы gif картинка запускалась по клику мыши, как ручка  на Погоде Яндекса?

Comment: а почему не сделать две картинки? одну статическую, а другую такую же, но gif (или даже серия картинок).

Comment: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568855/restart-animated-gif-as-background-image?rq=1) есть пример, как рестартовать анимацию.

Comment: А можно вообще спрайт из png, когда такой спрайт в движении и хорошо нарисован выглядит как флешка. Суть в том, чтобы сначала отобразить 1 кадр, дальше вызывается функция, которая запускает покадровую анимацию.

UPD В яндексе это реализовано так:
http://yandex.st/weather/1.1.82/i/1april/ruchka.png
а при клике запускается http://yandex.st/weather/1.1.82/i/1april/ruchka.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то в этом роде, но чтобы не срабатывало сразу, нужна статика однозначно!

```js
document.getElementById('bandit').onclick = function()
{
   this.src = this.src;        
}
```

```css
#bandit { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<img id="bandit" src="http://yandex.st/weather/1.1.82/i/1april/ruchka.gif" />
```

Comment: Отличный вариант. Скажите, а как заставить анимироваться картинку непрерывно по событию `onmouseover` ?