# Загрузка незацикленной gif-анимации по клику мыши

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код, который при клике, к примеру, на ячейку таблицы отображает в ней небольшую gif-анимацию. Анимация **НЕЗАЦИКЛЕНА**. Представляет собой просто анимированную галочку.

**html:**

```
....
<script src="mega_script.js" defer></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="f(this);"></td>
    <td onclick="f(this);"></td>
    <td onclick="f(this);"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
....
```

**mega_script.js:**

```
function f(obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = '<img src="images/ok.gif">';
}
```

При первом клике она загружается и анимируется нормально, при последующих кликах отображается уже проигравшая, неанимированная, гифка. Подскажите, как это преодолеть?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запуск gif-картинки по клику мыши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170164/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-gif-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8)

Comment: @Air. В возможном дубликате речь идёт о повторном запуске анимации одной и той же гифки, загруженной в одном месте. Мне же нужно по клику загружать гифку в разные места и, при этом, чтобы каждый раз анимация запускалась заново.

Comment: попробуй вот так function f(obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = '';
    obj.innerHTML = '<img src="images/ok.gif">';
}

Comment: но я думаю что он берет из кеша

Comment: @Air. Такой код уже пробовал - не помогает. О кеше думал, но в какую сторону копать, не знаю.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401260/Как-очистить-кэш-браузера-через-javascript

Comment: @Air. У меня чисто javascript. Без PHP.

Comment: выложи сюда весь код, будет легче понять, а то мы так в испорченный телефон играем